# Remember location(?) in Random seed?

Tags: java, random

First off: I'm mostly self-taught, so please forgive me if I don't know the correct terminology or make some rookie mistake.

So, I am making a Random variable with a seed.  When you're getting the "next" from the variable, it gets the next value from that seed.  Is there any way to record your location in a random variable?  For example, ideally the following code would output two identical strings:

```
//My attempt to save my location in a Random:

r = new Random(5);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.print(r.nextInt(2));
    if (i == 9) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}

//====================================

System.out.println("\n-------------");
r = new Random(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.print(r.nextInt(2));
}

r = new Random(r.nextLong());
System.out.print(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.print(r.nextInt(2));
}
```

but instead returns:

```
1001010100 1100110011
-------------
1001010100 0010010111
-------------
```

Is there some way to "remember" my location, such that I can create a new Random variable that would continue where the previous one left off?  Preferably, I'd rather not serialize the variable - it wouldn't be the end of the world, but I'm wondering if there's some other way.

Comment: That is not how seeding works. If you remove `r = new Random(r.nextLong())`, you will get the same results.

Comment: Just curious as to why you need to continue using the same seed since you will be generating new numbers regardless.

Comment: I was looking for a way to save the current place in the seed so that various attempts to save/reload a game wouldn't produce different results.  The obvious answer is to serialize the random variable, but I was looking for a way to do it that doesn't involve serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't generate `n` numbers with one seed, then use some other seed to start at where the previous series left off.

You can use the same seed again,and use a stream and skip the previous numbers you generated.

The last 5 values of the first list should equal the first 5 of the next.

```
        Random r = new Random(23);
        r.ints(10,1,100).forEach(a->System.out.print(a + " " ));
        System.out.println();

        r = new Random(23);

        r.ints(10,1,100).skip(5).forEach(a->System.out.print(a + " "));
```

You can also just continue using the same `Random` instance, since they don't expire.

```
       r = new Random(23);

        r.ints(5,1,100).forEach(a -> System.out.print(a + " "));
        r.ints(5,1,100).forEach(a -> System.out.print(a + " "));
```

Of course, if you want to keep the same object around for a long time or have huge numbers of random values to generate and keep track of then serialization is probably the best solution.

Comment: Thank you - this works for what I'm trying to do.  Using intstream with skip wasn't something I was aware of.